# An alternate definition of ideals

Tags: ideals, order-theory, filters

A *filter* on a poset if by definition its nonempty subset $F$ such that it does not contain the least element and $A, B \in F \Leftrightarrow \exists Z \in F : (Z \le A \wedge Z\le B)$ for every elements $A$, $B$ of our poset.

I will denote the class of all filters (on all posets) as $\mathfrak{F}$.

By definition an *ideal* is an image of a filter under the inclusion map into dual poset.

I will denote the class of all ideals (on all posets) as $\mathfrak{I}$.

Please help to find a short elegant proof of the following (desirably, using the above definition of ideal instead of the standard definition):

**Statement** $\mathfrak{J}\cap P = \theta[\mathfrak{F}\cap P]$ for every set $P$ of posets and a self-inverse order reversing isomorphism $\theta$ of $P$.

Comment: a key to this proof is decomposition $\theta = \operatorname{dual} \circ \omega$ where $\omega$ is an order isomorphism on $P$. It remains to fill proof details. It is easy to show that $\omega[\mathfrak{F}] = \mathfrak{F}$, but we need stronger formula $\omega[\mathfrak{F}\cap P] = \mathfrak{F}\cap P$

Comment: It seems that we need an additional condition: $P$ contains dual poset of each element of $P$